# Sorting a file of file paths based on type of ending (over 7000 lines)

Tags: c++, file, sorting

I am trying to sort a file (over 7000 lines) where each line is a file path from a server that I ssh'd into and put every single file path into one text file that is sorted alphabetically, and depending on the type of ending (.png, .jpg, .php, .html, .doc, etc.), and place those file paths in their own separate text file (for organization purposes).

Some example lines from the file:

```
./public_html/application/libraries/phpass-0.1/c/crypt_private.c
./public_html/creativity/archive/oldsite/curricular/revised ArtScience.10.1.doc
./public_html/chambers/Chambers Fund Guidelines9-1-2010 .pdf
./public_html/js/jquery-ui/development-bundle/demos/autocomplete/images/ui-anim_basic_16x16.gif
./tmp/webalizer/ssl/entrepreneurship.wfu.edu/hourly_usage_201112.png
./public_html/js/jquery-ui/development-bundle/demos/droppable/images/high_tatras2.jpg
./public_html/js/jquery-ui/development-bundle/demos/autocomplete/categories.html
```

The lines I've provided above represent only a very small amount of the different types of files I have to sort through. Some of them, after looking through the file either have more than one ending:

```
./public_html/creativity/archive/oldsite/home_images/_notes/home_nav_bottom.jpg.mno
```

or no ending at all:

```
./public_html/old/mambots/editors/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/plugins/insertdatetime
```

After thinking about how I would implement this in C++, this is the ROUGH outline (in pseudocode) of what I would do:

```
int main()
{
  /*have all necessary includes and namespaces*/
  /*initialize variables and do file opening*/

  while(/*we are not at end of file*/)
  {
      switch(/*by the type of file ending*/)
      {
          case .png:
            /*store it in a separate file just for .png lines*/
            break;
          case .jpg
            /*store it in a separate file just for .jpg lines*/
            break;
          /*have more cases to handle the rest of the type of endings*/
          case default:
             break;
      }

   }

   /*close file*/ 
   return 0;
}
```

And the questions that I have are the following:

1. How do I check line by line in the file that we have reached an ending like .jpg, .png, .php, etc.?
2. How do I account for all the different possible file endings (even though I've been through the whole file, I'm not exactly sure how many different endings there are) in my cases within my switch statement?
3. How do I handle the cases where a file path may have more than one ending (like the example I provided above)?
4. And of course, if there is a better way to do this using C++ (perhaps another language that would make this easier?), I'm all ears.

Comment: You're approach seems flawed. I would start by writing a comparator of some sort on the extension, then on the name in case of collision. Then this is a sorting question.

Comment: `std::map<std::string, vector<std::string>>` [or `std::unordered_map<...>`] seems like a useful tool for this - after you've constructed some code that splits the string, of course - most C libraries have a `splitpath` or similar function.

Comment: It sounds more like a job for shell or Perl/Python/... than for C++.  For a mere 7000 files, it won't take long.  You'll have to decide whether a `.jpg.mno` file is treated as `.mno` or `.jpg` or `.jpg.mno`, and whether `.tar.gz` is treated as `.gz` or `.tar` or `.tar.gz`.  Once you have an algorithm for dealing with the suffixes, then the rest is far simpler in scripting languages than in C++, unless you're a wizard in C++.

Comment: 7000 lines is *nothing* to today's computers, I wouldn't even mention it. Just read the whole file into memory and sort it.

Comment: Unless you're doing this for a class and thus must use C++ I suggest that a simple shell script using the [sort](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sort) command would probably be quicker to produce and less buggy. If you must do this in C++ you might look into the [qsort](http://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort) function. Best of luck.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I wouldn't consider myself a wizard in C++, but it's been a couple years since I have done any Python. Could you suggest any examples that I could look at in Python that would help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use the file extension as part of the file name in order to ensure separate files for different file types?

**A bit like this:**

```
int main()
{
  /*have all necessary includes and namespaces*/
  /*initialize variables and do file opening*/

  while(/*we successfully read a line from the file*/)
  {
      /* extract the file extension from end of line*/

      /* create a file name incorporating the file extension (table lookup?) */

      /* Append the line to the file of that file name */
   }

   /*close file*/
   return 0;
}
```

So your file names might be something like this:

```
list-of-jpg.txt
list-of-mpeg.txt
list-of-html.txt
etc...
```

**NOTES:**

A file extension can be extracted from the line like this:

```
std::string ext;
std::string::size_type pos = line.rfind('.');
if(pos != std::string::npos)
    ext = line.substr(pos + 1);
```

When a file has more than one ending it is usually the last that applies. For example a file with extension `.tar.gz` is a file that was creates as a `tar` but was later `gzipped`. So it is a now a gzip `gz`. So I would trust the last extension. It is likely the true format of the file that was converted from the previous extension's format.

Comment: What do you mean by "Table look up?"?

Comment: @TheD3ac Oh that was in case you might want something more descriptive than the plain extension for the file names. So you could have a look-up to convert the extension "jpg" into the name "JpegImages" for example. Or "html" -> "WebPages" etc...

Answer (score 0):

1. That depends how you read your strings, assuming you have a string per line it could be something like this:

   ```
   your_string.compare(your_string.length()-4, 4, ".jpg");
   ```

   Note that C++ does not support string compares with switch statements. To make things easier however, you could split the extension using `std::string::find()` together with `std::string::substr()` so you can just compare the extensions straight away.
2. That's what the `default` is for :)
3. With the above compare statement you could do that easily, just make sure you have the compound extensions before the separate ones.
4. awk or perl spring to mind, or just some basic shell scripting in general. Something like this would probably do the trick:

   ```
   awk -F '.' '{print $NF,$0}' your_file.txt | sort | cut -f2- -d'.'
   ```